# if else, fetchRow() zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
public function updateMemberdetail(Application_Model_Memberdetail $memberdetail)
{
    $data = array(
        'memberid' => $memberdetail->getMemberid(),
        'membername' => $memberdetail->getMembername(),
        'contact' => $memberdetail->getContact(),
        'birthday' => $memberdetail->getBirthday(),
        'email' => $memberdetail->getEmail(),
        'address' => $memberdetail->getAddress(),
    );

    $auth= Zend_Auth::getInstance(); //declare zend_auth to get instance
    $user= $auth->getIdentity(); //get identity of user
    $userid = $user->userid; //get userid of user

    $this->select() //select from usertable and memberdetail 
    ->from(array('memberdetail', 'usertable')) //join memberdetail and usertable through memberid = username 
    ->where('memberdetail.memberid = usertable.?', $userid); 
    $row = $this->fetchRow($select);
    if ($row == true) //if row exist update row
    {

        $this->update($data, 'memberid = '. (int)($memberdetail->getMemberid()));

    }
    else
    {

        $this->insert($data); //if row doesnt exist, add it

    }
}
```

Hello, I have some trouble with the if else statement. I want to add a row of data if it does not exist in the database, but update it if it exists. However, when I do not have the row in the DB, it does not insert it. When I manually insert a row into the DB, it does update the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetchRow method will return an instance of Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract, or NULL if not found. From Zend's [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.row.html#zend.db.table.row.write.insert), I believe you need to create the row before saving it.

```php
  $select = $this->select() //select from usertable and memberdetail 
    ->from(array('memberdetail', 'usertable')) //join memberdetail and usertable through memberid = username 
    ->where('memberdetail.memberid = usertable.?', $userid); 
  $row = $this->fetchRow($select);
  if (empty($row)) //if row exist update row
  {
    $newRow = $this->createRow($data);
    $newRow->save(); //if row doesnt exist, add it
  }
  else
  {
    $this->update($data, 'memberid = '. (int)($memberdetail->getMemberid()));
  }
```

Comment: Either a new row can be inserted or an old row can be updated,
I cant have a new row being inserted then updated.